# display block in navbar responsive CSS3 and media queries

Tags: css

I want to create a navbar responsive with html and CSS3. I use media queries for display or none a link bar that toggle menu (display on/off).

This code run correctly but I want to change display links menu in one line per link (or 2 maximum). But all the change in my code display always all the link in a same line.

for big screen my menu is on 1 line and for smaller screen the menu is toggle and display in 1 line per link (or 2 maximum).

My display block in media queries seem to be not run.

Can you help me to understand why media queries don't change my display engine for my link please.

HTML code

```
<nav id="navigation" class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li id="homeIcon"><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miltone/Y33w7/6/)

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You originally started selecting the lis by:

```
#navigation li
```

But when it got to media queries, you started to being more general about your selection for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px){
nav li
{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So, if you inspect the element, you will see that the #navigation li is overriding the media queries. Try changing your selection to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px)
{
#navigation li
{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I thought that nav li and #navigation li (which select nav) were the same...but no ! Ok and thanks you Dreds10 8-)